# Strange behavior of split String method

Tags: java, string, split

Consider these simple lines of code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet";
        String[] strings = string.split(",");

        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the output is the following:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

Now consider a variation of the previous code, in which I simply turned `,` into `|`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sit|amet";
        String[] strings = string.split("|");

        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the same exact output, but it is strangely the following:

```
L
o
r
e
m
|
i
p
s
u
m
|
d
o
l
o
r
|
s
i
t
|
a
m
e
t
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method accepts a regex and `|` have a special meaning in regex.

To see expected result escape that `|`.

```
String[] splits=string.split("\\|");
```

Or you can use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, to avoid all the mess.

```
String[] splits= string.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Comment: And if the separator is dynamic, e.g. passed as a parameter to your method, use `.split(Pattern.quote(separator))`.

Comment: @Andreas Agreed and I prefer the Pattern way only. I'm just clearing OP's doubt.